# BlackBerry browser error: The returned page had no content type, and therefore cannot be processed

Tags: blackberry, content-type, mobile-website

I'm developing a mobile web application and I'm currently testing my site against a handful of different devices, such as iPhone, Android, and some BlackBerries.

The BlackBerry Bold 9700 (OS 5.0.x) can access my site with no problem, but the BlackBerry Tour 9630 (OS 4.7.x) gives me the following error message when I try and access the site.

"The returned page had no content type, and therefore cannot be processed"

My only option is to click "Ok" and I can't access the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: I suppose you already checked if your (HTML?) page has its content type set to "text/html"? Is your webpage running on https?

Comment: The site is http, not https.  Here is how I'm declaring the page.

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Does anything look off here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending mime type with http headers. For asp.net you simply do

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm already setting the ContentType (as listed below) immediately after the head tag.

<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

The page works on other BlackBerry devices, but not the Tour.  I wonder if there's something with the OS of the Tour that doesn't accept the ContentType properly.  I'll continue to investigate.

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, kind of.  It will work if I add the explicit page to the url.  For example www.site.com/abc doesn't work, but www.site.com/abc/login.faces brings up the login page.  I'm using Java Server Faces 2.0.  Not sure what's up, but for now I'll use the full URL.